# I keep getting zeros when I call a procedure that should be calling data I know exists

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, method-call

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in MySQL and then call it back, and I have to submit a screenshot of the procedure returning a correct response. The code for storing the procedure seems to work fine (no errors, at least), but when I run the CALL function it returns 0.00 no matter which number I put in for @column3. My instructor thinks the issue is stating the OUT as AmountDue before I define the variable at the very top, but I couldn't figure out another way to have an input for @column3 in the CALL function without the IN/OUT constraints. I'm very new at this, obviously, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious...Anyone got any ideas?

Also, I don't need any help with building the database, adding tables, anything like that. The database exists and functions appropriately. Only need help on storing the procedure and calling it back. Thanks.

```
delimiter //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAmountDue;

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAmountDue(IN order_num INT, OUT AmountDue DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN
DECLARE AmountDue DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COST
INTO @AmountDue
FROM cake_shape
INNER JOIN ll_cakery.order
ON cake_shape.shape_id=order.shape_id
WHERE order_num=@order_num;

SELECT AmountDue;
END//

delimiter ;

CALL GetAmountDue('113',@AmountDue);
```

- order_num is a column with individual 3-character integer data values
- cost is a column with individual decimal(10,2) data values
- cake_shape is a table
- ll_cakery.order is a table (that doesn't work quite right because
  mysql has a command ORDER so I have to give the schema name)
- shape_id is a column, only used in the procedure for the join
- in the CALL function, @order_num=113

Comment: As written, you're not passing an integer to the procedure. `'@column3'` is a string that happens to have an @ as the first character. Remove the quotes.... `CALL GetAmountDue(@column3, @AmountDue);`. (And your code doesn't declare or initialise the variables mentioned in the `CALL`. Please update your question to include that too.)

Comment: @MatBailie I made the edits you requested, if you wouldn't mind taking another look. thanks :)

Comment: your edits don't work, as you donhave a @ order_num so you get to the same query as i have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passinf a string not an int

You don't compare column 3 with column1

Last you have to set the output variable with the data ou get from the select

Last never name variables like columns name, that brings only problems

> ```
> CREATE tABLE table1 ( COST DECIMAL(19,2),column2 int, column3 int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (10.2,1,1),(10.2,1,1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2 (column2 int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE GetAmountDue(IN _column1 INT, OUT _AmountDue DECIMAL(10,2))
> BEGIN
>
>
> SELECT SUM(COST)
> INTO @AmountDue
> FROM table1
> INNER JOIN table2
> ON table1.column2=table2.column2
> WHERE column3=_column1;
>
> SET _AmountDue := @AmountDue;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL GetAmountDue(1,@AmountDue);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @AmountDue
> ```
>
> ```
> | @AmountDue |
> | ---------: |
> |      20.40 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d07fcea190294c859af6f74056623686)*

Comment: this is not what I need it to do. thanks for the attempt, though

Comment: then explain you want a fiddle like my example helps to get  the idea by the way @ variables can only hold 1 valies

Comment: My query even with sum would give the correct answer, as you have only one cost in one of the tables, so i don't get what is wromng with my anser and your explanations don't help ealso as is i don't understand what you try to achieve

Comment: I don't need a sum, I need a select. I know an @ variable can only hold 1 value. I added some clarification to combine what I put in initially and my edits to try to be more clear. you don't have any idea how much data I have in the tables. I don't need a sum. there is significantly more data in the tables than you can see. I need the procedure to pull the particular cost associated with that order_num and present it as the @AmountDue. I'm sorry I assumed that was obvious.

Comment: the db is too big to put into that fiddle thing. sorry. hopefully the explanations help.

Comment: you need only the columns that matter cost and the ids and some data to show your points no need for the hole data base

Comment: ok i think i got it in the fiddle thing [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecdeeeab35655b940ab77c90b23a2ed9) never used that before, just put in the tables and columns used for the procedure. still getting null on the CALL

Comment: you didn't replicate my sample see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2856b1c281666a4ae8de4d26d83909c1

Comment: @SashaSeifert Fiddles don't need a whole replica of your database, they need enough example data to test the edge cases of the behaviour you desire.  Think unit tests, and/or read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SashaSeifert - Pay close attention to the differences between your fiddle and the one given to you.  Things like `WHERE Order_Num=@Order_Num` vs `WHERE Order_Num=_Order_Num`.  The answer here clearly works, so any changes you make that break it are changes that you shouldn't be making.

Comment: thank you both. i appreciate the help. i'm still learning and when the answers had syntax that was distinctly different from how i was taught in class i got confused. thanks again :)